# Setting up virtual users with vsftpd

Tags: ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I'm trying to set up virtual users for an FTP server in a Linux box, but I'm not sure if the server I've picked up (vsftpd) can do what I need. My requirements are:

1. The FTP accounts are inside a  real Linux user's home directory, let's call it "project". So the accounts need to be inside, say:

   - /home/project/../user1
   - /home/project/../user2
2. That user "project" needs to have shell access, but the virtual users don't.
3. The virtual users need to be chrooted inside their own subdirectories: that is, inside `/home/project/../user1`, `/home/project/../user2`, etc.
4. The uploaded files need to have the same UID/GID as the "project" user.

Now, my point is contention is that, according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04), vsftpd cannot do this:

> ...When chroot is enabled for local users, they are restricted to their
>   home directory by default. However, because of the way vsftpd secures
>   the directory, it must not be writable by the user.

The solution they offer is to create a subfolder inside the user's directory, make it owned by "nobody" and remove write permissions for the user... but that's not what I need. I need everything inside that subdirectory to be owned and writable by the original user.

Is there any way to do this? Perhaps with a different FTP server?